# Merge LINQ queries on different xdocument elements into one where?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to merge these two LINQ queries but I'm a little confused. I decided to do them in two different queries as they seemed a little complicated. Is it possible to merge these?

```
foreach (var xe in document.Descendants("post"))
{
    var itemss = xe.Elements("photo-url")
                   .Where(x => x.Attribute("max-width").Value == "1280" && 
                               x.Value == "www.tumblr.com");

    var itemssss = xe.Elements("photoset")
                     .Where(x => x.Descendants("photo-url").Any(y => y.Attribute("max-width").Value == "1280" && y.Value != "www.tumblr.com"));
}
```

Comment: It would be great to know the full structure of the XML. Given your query I can see there is potentially some refactoring but I can't tell for sure without seeing the full XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just concatenation....

```
var merged = itemss.Concat(itemssss);
```